# material ui Textfield with type number up-down arrow stopped working in mozila firefox accidentally

Tags: material-ui

"Textfield code from material ui docs"

```
<TextField
      id="outlined-number"
      label="Number"
      type="number"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

From this issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26747, it seems that browser version is the cause. Upgrade it should resolve your problem.